# Cannot open PDF files when the extension is in capital letter

Tags: applications, pdf

On my Android tablet, it is not possible to open a PDF where "PDF" is written in capital Letters. If I rename the file, it is opened with Google PDF viewer. The error is: "File can't be opened".

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: So just for clarification: Let's say you have a file called `example.PDF` that won't open. Are you saying that it works fine if you rename it to `example.pdf`?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this error?

Comment: Could you perhaps add more information to your question? Which device are you using, which version of Android? Is the file on your SD Card (or `/sdcard/` partition) or is it somewhere else?

Comment: I have the same problem. Using a Galaxy S5 running 6.0.1 thru Sprint, I have a few different PDF viewers installed. The system tries to open it with the MEMO app. Doesn't give you any other options. When you select MEMO it cannot open the file. Tried looking through the default apps and the App Manager and cannot find neither my PDF viewers or the MEMO app listed to change defaults or reset them.

Comment: It is a problem with the android version or your pdf viewer.  On Android 13, I have tried several viewers, they all work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual, you can't fix the misbehavior exhibited by any app. This is unlike Windows, where you could edit the registry to resolve such issues. With Android, Google effectively owns your phone, and they take extensive measures to prevent you from making modifications or fixes.

Your only option is to install a new PDF handler such as [Acrobat Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader&hl=en&gl=US) or the Drive PDF viewer (invariably bundled with Google Drive).